# JSF2 updating composite elements using ajax

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, rendering, composite-component

There's an input element and I want to update it once the user enters something in there.

input element:

```
<h:form id="form">
    <h:inputText value="#{message.message}"> 
        <f:ajax event="keyup" render="form:compElem"/> 
    </h:inputText> 
    <compositeOutputComponents:test2 id="compElem" message="#{message.message}"/>
</h:form>
```

and this is how my composite element looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:composite="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite">
  <h:head>
  </h:head>
    <h:body>
            <fieldset>
                <composite:interface>
                    <composite:attribute name="id"/>
                    <composite:attribute name="message" required="true"/>
                </composite:interface>
                <composite:implementation>
                    <span id="#{cc.attrs.id}">
                        <h:outputText value="#{cc.attrs.message}"/>
                    </span>
                </composite:implementation>
            </fieldset>
    </h:body>
```

I tried to pass id to the composite element as Balus in [JSF Updating Composite Component (Primefaces)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11690635/jsf-updating-composite-component-primefaces) suggested (I dont use primefaces), but still page yields an error : "malformedXML: During update: form:compElem not found". When i use non composite element everything works fine.

Comment: The error message contradicts with the code. The code contains the wrong render ID, but the error message shows the right render ID. What is it now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `#{cc.clientId}` instead of `#{cc.attrs.id}` in the composite implementation.

```
<span id="#{cc.clientId}">
```

Otherwise it will end up as `<span id="compElem">` instead of `<span id="form:compElem">` and then JavaScript can't find it anymore, resulting in this malformedXML error.

Once you fix that part, then you can just reference it in `<f:ajax render>` the usual way like as you would reference any other non-composite component in the same form:

```
<f:ajax ... render="compElem" />
```

or if you insist in specifying absolute client IDs for some reason (but this is thus unnecessary):

```
<f:ajax ... render=":form:compElem" />
```

#### See also:

- [Referring composite component ID in f:ajax render](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13313207/referring-to-a-composite-component-from-a-using-page-fails/)
- [How to find out client ID of component for ajax update/render? Cannot find component with expression "foo" referenced from "bar"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634156/how-to-reference-components-in-jsf-ajax-cannot-find-component-with-identifier/8644762#8644762)

Comment: It's not clear for me where `cc.clientId` and `compElem` come from. Afaik `cc.clientId` is a placeholder for the `id` attribute assigned to the composite component element (when it's used) (assigned by the user or JSF). `compElem` is an example for an `id` chosen by the composite component creator, right? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8412914/how-to-reference-cc-clientid-in-ajax-update-process-render-execute explains it better imo.

Comment: @Karl, as usual, the "See also" links contain further explanation.