# update primefaces composite component from itself

Tags: jsf, primefaces, composite-component

I create a composite component in PrimeFaces 4.

```
<composite:interface>
    <composite:attribute name="title" required="true"/>
    <composite:attribute name="widgetVar" required="true" />
    <composite:attribute name="controller" required="true" type="com.controller.AbstractController" />
</composite:interface>
<composite:implementation>
    <div id="#{cc.clientId}" style="width: 100%;">
        <p:dialog widgetVar="#{cc.attrs.widgetVar}" header="#{msgs[cc.attrs.title]}" width="500">
                <p:panelGrid styleClass="borderLessGrid" columns="1" id="mainPanel" style="width:100%;">
                    <p:panel style="width: 100%; text-align: left; direction: ltr;" id="btnPanel">
                        <ui:repeat value="#{cc.attrs.controller.commands}" var="command">
                            <p:commandButton
                                    value="#{command.value}" title="#{command.title}"
                                    style="width: 50px;"
                                    disabled="#{not command.enable}" actionListener="#{command.onClick}"
                                    update="@this"/>
                        </ui:repeat>
                    </p:panel>
                    <p:panel style="width: 100%">
                        <p:scrollPanel mode="native" style="width: 100%; height: 300px; border: none;">
                            <p:tree value="#{cc.attrs.controller.rootNode}" var="node" id="tree"
                                    selectionMode="single"
                                    style="vertical-align:top; float:right; width: 95%; border: none;">
                                <p:ajax event="select"
                                        listener="#{cc.attrs.controller.onTreeItemSelect}"
                                        update="#{cc.clientId}"/>
                                <p:treeNode id="treeNode"
                                            expandedIcon="ui-icon-folder-open"
                                            collapsedIcon="ui-icon-folder-collapsed">
                                    <p:outputLabel value="#{node}" id="lblNode"/>
                                </p:treeNode>
                            </p:tree>
                        </p:scrollPanel>
                    </p:panel>
                    <p:panel style="width: 100%">
                        <p:scrollPanel mode="native" style="width: 100%; height: 100px; border: none;">
                            <p:outputLabel />
                        </p:scrollPanel>
                    </p:panel>
                </p:panelGrid>
        </p:dialog>
    </div>
</composite:implementation>
```

I will when user click on tree element it update all parts of my component. But when i enter page url in explorer it give me following error :

> Cannot find component with expression "conditionCreator" referenced from "conditionCreator:tree"

Do you have any solution for it.
Thanks.

**update : 2014-24-12**
I read the [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8412914/how-to-reference-cc-clientid-in-ajax-update-process-render-execute) but it does not work. i dont know where is problem but when i use this solution it refresh all of my page.

Comment: Ops. It solved via jQuery selector APIs. Meet the following link for more details: [jQuery Selector API meets JSF](http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=1867)